# spark 2.x write to parquet by partition compared to hdfs extremely slow

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-s3, hdfs

Can't figure out where to start troubleshooting why a simple write to parquet by partition from spark/scala into hdfs would be matter of a few seconds versus a few minutes when I write to s3 instead.

```
    def saveDF(df: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame) : Unit = {

      df.write
        .mode("overwrite")
        .option("compression", "snappy")
        .partitionBy("col")
//        .parquet(s"hdfs://localhost:9000/${fileout}") // this is a few seconds
        .parquet(s"s3a://${s3bucket}/${s3folder}/${fileout}") // this is a few minutes
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

try following configuration to improve performance

```
--conf "spark.sql.parquet.enable.summary-metadata=false"\
--conf "spark.hadooop.mapreduce.fileoutputcommitter.algorithm.version=2"\
```

However, you won't achieve same performance as with hdfs. The problem is with commit algorithm and commit implementation in s3(move from _temporary folder in s3 is not O(1) as in hdfs, but rather O(n))

Answer (score 1):

That's because your HDFS cluster co-habits your AWS EMR cluster and your s3 access needs to move data across the data center.